# Transform Image during transformPage in Viewpager Android

Tags: android

I want to transform image when view pager slides. i have seen that when Viewpager slides then

```
public void transformPage(View view, float f)
```

is called. In this function i want to add functionality so that when view slides like 1 to 2 or 2 to 3 then some image from 1st page should go to 2nd screen.

I want to implement functionality like GROFERS Android App Welcome Screen.

Please Help me

Comment: It is a Android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grofers.customerapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using this -

```
 public void transformPage(View view, float f) {
            if(view.getTag() != null) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
                if (f >= -1F && f < 1.0F) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        animateOnFirstScreen(f);
                    } else {
                        if (i == 1) {
                            animateOnSecondScreen(f);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (i == 2) {
                            animateOnThirdScreen(f);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void animateOnFirstScreen(float f)
    {
        if (f <= 0.0F)
        {
            f = Math.abs(f);
            posX = (TEXT_GROCERY_MART_FINAL_X - TEXT_GROCERY_MART_INIT_X) * f + TEXT_GROCERY_MART_INIT_X;
            textGroceryMart.setTranslationX(posX);
            posY = (TEXT_GROCERY_MART_FINAL_Y - TEXT_GROCERY_MART_INIT_Y) * f + TEXT_GROCERY_MART_INIT_Y;
            textGroceryMart.setTranslationY(posY);

              imageMuffin.setAlpha(0.0F);
                imageEnergyDrink.setAlpha(0.0F);
                imageMuffin.setScaleX(0.0F);
                imageEnergyDrink.setScaleX(0.0F);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you send full example i try it but can't do successfully. Thank you

Comment: view.getTag() return null always

Comment: Can you please tell me how to setTag() for viewpager?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing image based on the page your are in using position

```
 public void transformPage(View view, float f)
    {
      int position=(int)f;
      switch(f)
      {
       case 1:
         imageview.setImageResource(R.id.youimageID);
         break;
       case 2: //so on ..
      }
    }
```

Comment: how to transfer image from one page to another

Comment: transfer image means? passing to next page?

Answer (score 1):

It took me two and half days to make it flawless at Grofers. If you give it a closer look, everything you see moving from one fragment to another is not actually moving from one fragment to another.

There is a ViewPager inside activity and fragments of viewPager contain static images. And all the images which you see moving are inside the activity itself and not inside the fragments.

**When to transform images?**

When you receive callbacks from ViewPager

```
public void transformPage(View view, float f) { 
    ...
}
```

You can make the transformation of the images inside the activity depending of which fragment is entering and which one is leaving the view.

**How will you know which fragment is entering and which one is leaving?**

While creating fragments to be added to ViewPager you can attach a tag to every fragment

```
rootView.setTag(tag)
```

Tag can be an integer representing the position of the fragment inside ViewPager.

```
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
int tag = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
    } else if (position < 1) { // [-1,1]
        // Decide which fragment is sliding left and which one is sliding right.
        if (tag == 0)
            // Transformation between the first and second fragment
        else if (tag == 1)
            // Transformation between first, second and third fragment
        else if (tag == 2)
            // Transformation between the third and fourth fragment
    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
    }
}
```

**What things need to be taken care of?**

- You need to take care of aspect ratio of different types of screens
  so that it can scale according to different screen sizes.
- Take care of transformation of all the images even if the images are off-screen (otherwise you will see some bugs like some images are visible in some other screen while scrolling through different fragments).